A way to move an object with the 3D cursor location as the moving point?
I want to move an object, such as a box, so that a specific corner point of the object is at a specific x,y,z, so I've placed the 3D cursor on the specific corner point of my object, but how can I now move the object so that the 3D cursor/corner point location is the moving point of the the object?

What do you mean by "moving point"? Maybe set the Transform Pivot Point on the top toolbar to 3D Cursor?

If by "moving point" you mean the Object Origin then there are a couple things you can do. This is all assuming you have the 3D Viewport Pie Menu addon enabled (it's built-in and mandatory IMO).
Origin

In edit mode you can use the Shift+S > Cursor To Selected to snap the cursor to any selection, then you could do Ctrl+X > Origin to Cursor but you can do both in one step by just using the Origin to Selected option there.
This will permanently change the object origin. Not always desirable.


As of recently (I think like 3.9 or maybe 4.0) you can quick add a temp origin for snapping objects in Object mode. Press G to start moving the object then press B to select a new snap point, LMB to confirm the choice, then you can snap the object to other objects with that "origin". It takes a second to wrap your head around how it works but it does the trick.

Then if you aren't using "moving point" to refer to the object origin and mean to say "Transform Pivot Point" then you do that by pressing the Period key and selecting 3D Cursor. More info here.

Ah thank you for all the info, this just what I was looking for, especially the non-origin movement/translation shown in the last animation. Thanks again.

If this answer solves your problem then can you accept it so that it gets removed from the unanswered questions queue.
